# fs.readFile works, but readFileSync returns empty content

Tags: node.js, fs

The following block of code leaves the `content` variable empty:

```
const file = fs.createWriteStream("/home/pi/rpi-main/descriptor.json");

http.get(url, function (response) {
    let content;

    response.pipe(file);
    content = fs.readFileSync("/home/pi/rpi-main/descriptor.json", { encoding: "utf-8" });
});
```

However, if I read the file using fs.readFile, the content is what it should be.

Why is this happening with the synchronous call?

Comment: Where in your code are you using `content`?

Answer (score 3):

It's because `pipe` is an async function, so when you call `readFileSync` it actually hasn't begun writing anything to the file.

You should read your file in the callback for the  `finish` event of the pipe.

```
response.pipe(file).on('finish', () => {
    content = fs.readFileSync(filename, { encoding: "utf-8" });
});
```